# JavaFx Application Not Working

Tags: javafx, java-8

I have created this simple JavaFx Application using Fxml File
Whenever I call main Method in Main Class I get an Exception.
Before this I was getting NPE in FXMLLoader method which was solved but now I am getting Class Not Found Exception.
From Trace I am not able to guess Exactly which Class is missing at Run Time.
I am using Eclipse IDE and Downloaded the Eclipse Plugin for JAVAFX

This is Main Class

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;



public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            AnchorPane root=(AnchorPane)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("application/sample.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
            primaryStage.setTitle("DialogBox");
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

sample.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.geometry.insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>


<AnchorPane fx:controller="application.Controller"
        xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10">
```

Below is the StackTrace

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/Dayanand/workspace/FX1/bin/application/sample.fxml

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(FXMLLoader.java:2848)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processImport(FXMLLoader.java:2692)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processProcessingInstruction(FXMLLoader.java:2661)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2517)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at application.Main.start(Main.java:18)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadType(FXMLLoader.java:2899)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(FXMLLoader.java:2846)
    ... 20 more
```

Kindly Help Thank You

Comment: Post your controller class

Comment: `javafx.geometry.insets` should be `javafx.geometry.Insets`

Comment: oh Yes Thats What i Missed Thank you